# Using built-in Angular Validators on a FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Using FormBuilder, I instantiate a FormArray for an array of email fields. I assign it a set of `Validator`s, which includes a custom `Validator`, and Angular's built-in `Validators.email`.

```
this.formBuilder.array(
    [this.formBuilder.control('')], 
    Validators.compose([customValidator, Validators.email])
)
```

Assigning the `Validator`s in this way means that the `FormArray` is passed as the `control` parameter to the Validators. My custom validator can be tuned to expect a `FormArray`, but `Validators.email` expects a `FormControl` with a single value.

How do I use Angular built-in Validators with a `FormArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formbuild array method specify that `validatorOrOpts or asyncValidator` parameters gone to run on the form array itself not the controls of the array so there are two solution

1. add the validator to the control it self

   ```
      this.formBuilder.array(
       [this.formBuilder.control('',Validators.email)], 
       Validators.compose([customValidator])
   )
   ```
2. create a custom validator and trigger angular validator on each array controls

```js
function customArrayEmailValidator(formArray: FormArray) {
  if (formArray.length > 0) {
    for (let c of formArray.controls) {
      let state = Validators.email(c)
      if (state !== null) {
        return { emailInValid: state }
      }
    }
    return null;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

but it 's still look the same like the first way

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53528199)

[FormBuilder - Array](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#array)

Comment: The first solution is unfortunate, because of course that would have to be applied for every individual control added to the array. I guess the second solution works as well as it possibly can, if less clean than some Angular built-in way.